# asp.net mvc usercontrol viewdata

Tags: asp.net-mvc, user-controls, viewdata

i have user control, which i render on several views. i want to show viewdata in the usercontrol, but viewdata must be filled in controller method, so i need to fill viewdata  on each controller method of each view, where i render usercontrol.
is there any simple solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a controller for that control like

MenuController

with an action method

```
RenderMenu()
{
    **do your work to get the data here and preferrably strong type it**
    return PartialView("NameOfYourAscxFile", yourObject);
}
```

If you name your control RenderMenu.ascx, you can just do

```
RenderMenu()
{
    **do your work to get the data here and preferrably strong type it**
    return PartialView(yourObject);
}
```

Or, maybe it would make more sense to name it Menu.ascx and have a method Menu like this

```
Menu()
{
    **do your work to get the data here and preferrably strong type it**
    Menu myMenuObject = Repository.GetMenu(...);
    return PartialView(myMenuObject);
}
```

Your Menu.ascx start would look like this

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<mynamespace.Menu>" %>
```

To use it in a View you do it like this:

```
<% Html.RenderAction("Menu", "Menu"); %>
```

HTH